# `nvm list` does not show the current version of node installed

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have installed node v20.11.1 and deleted the previous version I was using, v18.16.0. But when I use `nvm list` command it does not show the currently installed v20.11.1 instead shows only v18.16.0.

There are similar questions but none of it answers my issue. Below here is the image of my windows 11 terminal.

is there anything wrong about my machine?

[image: terminal]

tried `nvm list` and I was expecting only v20.11.1 but it showed v18.16.0

Comment: Use volta instead of nvm easy to use . And you can choose node version project wise. https://volta.sh/

Comment: I use both. My question is why nvm is doing that